# How to organize 2 level array to a custom dictionary format?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm trying to convert this array

```
a = [
        ['A','B','C'],
        [1,33,45],
        [721,22,9]
    ]
```

to a dictionary in order to have this output:

```
b = { 
    'A':[1,721],
    'B':[33,22],
    'C':[45,9]
}
```

My current code is like this, getting this error:

```
b = {}

for i in range(1,len(a)):
    for j in range(len(a[i])):
        b[a[0][j]].append(a[i][j])
        
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
KeyError: 'A'
```

May someone help me in how would be a way to do it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found your issue:

```
KeyError: 'A'
```

If you debugg it,you will find that:
[image]
But `b` is a empty dictionary,it surely will raise Exception.

Just followed by your code, you could just change

```
b = {}
```

to

```
from collections import defaultdict

....
b = defaultdict(list)
```

is okay.(The rest of the code does not need to be changed)

---

Other ideas:

```
b = dict(zip(a[0], zip(*a[1:]))) # {'A': (1, 721), 'B': (33, 22), 'C': (45, 9)}

b = dict(zip(a[0], map(list,zip(*a[1:])))) # {'A': [1, 721], 'B': [33, 22], 'C': [45, 9]}

b = dict(zip(a[0], [list(i) for i in zip(*a[1:])])) # {'A': [1, 721], 'B': [33, 22], 'C': [45, 9]}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I select your solution because of the other ways you shared. In which application did you do the debug? And what does mean the asterisk in `zip` comand?

Comment: @GerCas `the asterisk` seems like `unzip`.You could refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters).

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a nested dictionary comprehension, looping first over the key values in `a[0]` and then the individual values in the other lists in `a`:

```
b = { k : [a[j][i] for j in range(1, len(a))] for i, k in enumerate(a[0]) }
```

Output:

```
{'A': [1, 721], 'B': [33, 22], 'C': [45, 9]}
```

Comment: Thanks Nick for your help sharing your solution

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
from collections import defaultdict


result = defaultdict(list)

for i in a[1:]:  # start from second list
    for k, v in zip(a[0], i):
        result[k].append(v)

print(dict(result))  # {'A': [1, 721], 'B': [33, 22], 'C': [45, 9]}
```